# Measuring the time of an interactive command called from a script

Tags: command-line, redirect

Assuming I want to track the times I spend editing a set of files, and log them to a file, as I could do from the commandline using the `time` command:

```
time vim test.txt
```

I get

```
real    0m8.149s
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Fine. Now if I want to append its output to a log file,

```
time vim test.txt >> my.log
```

Well, of course I'd make that more elaborate eventually to give me more information, but I don't get past the first step, the terminal just hangs with the following warning:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

The redirection interferes with vim needing the terminal. What would be a good workaround here?

Edit: One workaround could be the following:

```
time gnome-terminal -x vim test.txt >> my.log
```

Which opens a new terminal window in which vim is executed. I'd prefer to stay in the same window, but could also live with this workaround.

Edit: Didn't quite work either, it seemed to do in some test, in some other it backgrounded, thus not measuring the time used. In my script now I did something like that:

```
/usr/bin/time -o tmpfile vim test.txt 
echo some stuff `cat tmpfile` some more stuff >>my.log
rm tmpfile
```

Seems to work.

Edit: It works only as long as one doesn't have two processes using the same `tmpfile`. In order to avoid that one can use the pid of the script being executed as part of the temporary file name:

```
/usr/bin/time -o $$.tmp vim test.txt 
echo some stuff `cat $$.tmp` some more stuff >>my.log
rm $$.tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which `time` are you using? The Bash builtin or the one in `/usr/bin/time`? If you use `/usr/bin/time` (and read `man time`) you'll find that you can log the output to a file, format the output any way you like, .... The Bash builtin `time` is much less capable.

Comment: Yes, I also found about that, see edit above.